# Developing wordpress sites on Docker for Windows

Tags: wordpress, windows, docker

It took me a while but I finally setup Wordpress in Docker for windows, the install went fine and I have a working wordpress site at `http://localhost:8080` I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the wordpress files, such as everything in `wp-content`. I know they live in the container, but how do I go about developing with my code editor, I need to edit stuff in the `themes` folder.

I have seen in a tutorial that said to map my directories like this in my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
     - wordpress/wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

I don't see how this helps be get to my files, I am running windows so I need to access them in my `C` drive ideally in `C/Users/Andersk/Sites/Wordpress...` I will include my current `docker-compose.yml` file below. Hopefully some one can help. Thanks

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the Docker icon in your system tray and select *Settings*, then click on *Shared Drives*. Make sure your C: drive is shared.

Now you should be able to add this to `wordpress` service section in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
     - C:/Users/Andersk/Sites/Wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, I have been struggling with this all day, now I can do my development in docker tomorrow. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Docker and Wordpress, sounds like a perfect Christmas - enjoy! :-)